# Calculating Gini by Row in R

Tags: r, gini

stackoverflow.

I'm trying to calculate the gini coefficient within each row of my dataframe, which is 1326 rows long, by 6 columns (1326 x 6).

My current code...

```
attacks$attack_gini  <- gini(x = c(attacks$attempts_open_play,
attacks$attempts_corners,attacks$attempts_throws,
attacks$attempts_fk,attacks$attempts_set_play,attacks$attempts_penalties))
```

... fills all the rows with the same figure of 0.7522439 - which is evidently wrong.

Note: I'm using the gini function from the reldist package.

Is there a way that I can calculate the gini for the 6 columns in each row?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function `gini` of `reldist` does not accept a dataframe as an input. You could easily get the coefficient of the first column of your dataframe like this:

```
> gini(attacks$attempts_open_play)
[1] 0.1124042
```

However when you do `c(attacks$attempts_open_play, attacks$attempts_corners, ...)` you are actually generating one list with all the columns of your dataframe just after the other, thus your gini call gives back a single number, e.g.:

```
> gini(c(attacks$attempts_open_play, attacks$attempts_corners))
[1] 0.112174
```

And that's why you are assigning the same single number to every row at `attacks$attack_gini`. If I understood properly, you what to calculate the gini coefficient for the values of your columns per row, you can use [apply](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/apply.html), something like

```
attacks$attack_gini <- apply(attacks[,c('attempts_open_play', 'attempts_corners', ...)], 1, gini)
```

where the 2nd parameter with value 1 is applying the function `gini` per row.

```
head(apply(attacks[,c('attempts_open_play', 'attempts_corners')], 1, gini))
[1] 0.026315789 0.044247788 0.008928571 0.053459119 0.019148936 0.007537688
```

Hope it helps.